# Can Nginx work as Direct Server Return load balancer?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

Is there a way to configure Nginx to work as a Direct Server Return (DSR) load balancer similar to this:
http://blog.haproxy.com/2011/07/29/layer-4-load-balancing-direct-server-return-mode/

Comment: Not really. Nginx (open source) doesn't really claim to be a generic load balancer at all and I don't think the paid version currently supports DSR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this you need `transparent` parameter of Nginx proxy_bind directive which is available on Nginx Plus R10 or Nginx 1.11.2+. Also you need to configure routing table and firewall for IP transparency and `tc` for direct server response. A working example is fully described here:
https://www.nginx.com/blog/ip-transparency-direct-server-return-nginx-plus-transparent-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with either HAProxy and nginx because they act as reverse proxies, above the OSI Layer 4.
For Load-balancing in DSR mode, you want to use LVS, at kernel layer, which works at OSI layer 3 and 4, and analyze packets per packets.

Baptiste